# Disabled Play command when the asset has custom delivery policies in windows media azure

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

The Play command in the Content tab is now disabled for assets that have a custom delivery policy created programmatically using the SDK/REST API.

http://blogs.southworks.net/mconverti/2015/02/23/more-azure-management-portal-updates-for-azure-media-services/

Comment: Do you have a question you would like to ask?

Comment: yes. 
my exact question is i tried to upload encrypted(AES with SWT Token) video with through c# code to Windows Azure media service. 
It uploaded success fully. But how can i check its working or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. If you have multiple asset delivery policy configured, there won't be played back enabled in portal.

Comment: Thanks for Reply @Mingfei Yan,
      How can i create Single assest delivery policy through code. how can i check the multiple assest is encrypted correctly?..  

advance thanks

Comment: @Kanyaraj, you can definitely check it using APIs. however, if you want a visual tool, I suggest you try Azure Explorer Tool, and check information on each asset. hhttps://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer

Answer (score 0):

You could download this tool (Azure Explorer Tool -which is a winform desktop tool) to get more details on your asset (content key, content key authorization policy and asset delivery policy). This is the link for the tool: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer

I will add a blog to explain later.

Cheers,
Mingfei yan